# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given when i used if condition

Tags: laravel

I want to make if condition for output $tourCheck if 'tour_id' exists in my table, for example as 5 for a specific user  then do not apply the function, but if it exists then apply the function
(I mean the user cannot apply on this function more than one time)

```
public function addtour(Request $request,$id)
{
    $tourCheck = DB::table('teckets')->select('tour_id')->where('user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(9);

    if (in_array($id, $tourCheck))
    {
        DB::table('tours')->where('id', $id)->update(['counter' => DB::raw('counter +1')]);

        $form_data = array('user_id' => $request->input("user_id", auth::user()->id), 'tour_id' => $request->input('tour_id', $id),);

        tecket::create($form_data);

        return view('submit_tour');
    }else{
        return view('submit_tour')->with('you already get a tecket for this tour');
    }

}
```

Comment: `$tourCheck` is not an array, it's a Collection, wichs is also an object.

Comment: then how can i use it with if condition ?

Comment: Just transfrom the `$tourCheck` with `toArray()` method and the statement should work.

Comment: the same error appears

Comment: Iterate the Collection with foreach.

Comment: can you do an example for it ?

Comment: why are you paginating that data?

Comment: i took it copy and paste and i didnt delete it yet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current code you don't need to be checking an array at all, you can have the database do the check:

```
public function addTour(Request $request, $id)
{
    $tourCheck = DB::table('teckets')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('tour_id', $id)
        ->exists();

    if (! $tourCheck) {
        tecket::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'tour_id' => $id,
        ]);

        DB::table('tours')->where('id', $id)->increment('counter');

        return view('submit_tour');
    }

    return view('submit_tour')->with('message', 'you already have a tecket for this tour.');
}
```

You could probably help yourself out a little bit by setting up a relationship between Tour and User, Tecket. Then you could also hook into the events and have the tour counter update when creating a tecket.

You could even do this with `firstOrCreate` as well to cut this down more:

```
public function addTour(Request $request, $id)
{
    $tecket = tecket::firstOrCreate([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'tour_id' => $id,
    ]);

    if ($tecket->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        DB::table('tours')->where('id', $id)->increment('counter');
        return view('submit_tour');
    }

    return view('submit_tour')->with(...);
}
```